# Definition of Hölder space

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, definition

I am wondering what is the definition for Hölder space $C^\gamma$ when $\gamma\in \mathbb{N}$.

Let's take the underlying field $\mathbb{R}^d$.
Is it 
$$
C^\gamma = \{f:\ f\in C^{\gamma-1}\}\cap \{f: \partial^\alpha f\in Lip,\ |\alpha| = \gamma-1\}
$$
or common space
$$C^\gamma = \{f: \|\partial^\alpha f \|_\infty<\infty, |\alpha|\leq \gamma\}.$$

I guess I would be the first one, otherwise I don't see why we need Zygmund space to fill the gap.

Comment: In general the space of Lipschitz functions is denoted by $C^{0,1}$ whhile the space of continuously differentiable functions is denoted by $C^1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's focus on spaces rather than notation. We have:

- The space of functions with continuous derivatives of orders $\le k$. Usually denoted $C^k$.
- The space of functions with continuous derivatives of orders $\le k$, where the $k$th derivative is Hölder continuous of order $\alpha\in (0,1]$. Usually denoted $C^{k,\alpha}$ but sometimes also $C^{k+\alpha}$. The latter notation is a bit dangerous because $C^{1+1}$ is not the same as $C^{2}$.
- The space of functions with bounded weak derivatives of orders up to $k$. Usually denoted $W^{k,\infty}$.

We have $C^{k,1}\subseteq W^{k+1,\infty}$, because Lipschitz functions have bounded weak derivatives of first order. If the spaces are considered on a sufficiently nice domain (without cusps, slits etc.) then $C^{k,1} = W^{k+1,\infty}$. In particular, this is the case for $\mathbb R^d$.

> I don't see why we need Zygmund space to fill the gap.

Notation is a wrong place to look  for a reason why some object was introduced. A major reason to introduce the Zygmund space is the behavior of the Hilbert transform (and other singular integral operators) on $C^{k,\alpha}$. When $0<\alpha<1$, the space is mapped onto itself. When $\alpha=1$, it isn't: e.g., the transform of a Lipschitz function isn't Lipschitz. But the slightly larger Zygmund space turns out to be preserved by  the Hilbert transform. Hence, we can conclude that the   transform of a Lipschitz function is a member of the Zygmund class.

Comment: Nice answer +1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The motivation of my question is that I have learnt Zygmund space $C_*^\gamma$ as a special case of Besov space, i.e. $B_{\infty,\infty}^\gamma$. I don't really see the relation among these spaces. In Triebel's book "Theory of function spaces II" he mentioned Zygmund space was introduced to 'fill the gap'.

Comment: @newbie You don't see the relation between which spaces? One of the definition of [Besov space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Besov_space) uses second-order differences $\omega^2$, and so does the Zygmund space. Setting $p=q=\infty$ results in taking the supremum of $\omega^2$ over all scales $(q=\infty)$ and locations $(p=\infty)$. Triebel may have made the remark from the perspective of a function spaces expert. But Zygmund came to these spaces from the studies of trigonometric series and polynomials: [see here](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Zygmund_class_of_functions).

Comment: Is $C^{1,1}$ same as $C^2$, given that underlying field $\mathbb{R}^d$ and equipped with the norm i given in question? Since boundedness of all derivatives is required, it implicitly requires Lipschitz condition.

Comment: @newbie In your question, the *first* definition of $C^\gamma$ is what I denoted by $C^{\gamma-1,1}$. The *second* definition is  unclear, because you did not specify in what sense $\partial_\alpha f$ should exist. If you ask for derivatives of order up to $\gamma$ to exist at every point and to be bounded, you get a space of such little use that it has no common name or notation.

Comment: What about if the latter derivative is in the sense of distribution?

Comment: @newbie Then you get the same space as $C^{\gamma-1,1}$ in my answer. See the discussion of $W^{k,\infty}$ there.